# How to dispose of a managed resource used by task? (Not .NET 4.5)

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

The particular scenario I am dealing with involves a SqlConnection and SqlCommand being used in conjunction with a task.  I want to know how best to dispose of the SqlConnection and SqlCommand when the task completes.  Lets say I have these two objects:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(base._ConnectionString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SomeProcedure", connection);
```

I am considering two different ways of handling this.

The first is to use a continuation to clean everything up.

```
return Task.Factory
    .FromAsync<int>(
        beginMethod: command.BeginExecuteNonQuery,
        endMethod: command.EndExecuteNonQuery,
        state: null)
    .ContinueWith(a =>
        {
            if (command != null)
            {
                command.Dispose();
            }
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Dispose();
            }
            // Need to propagate the exception too if one occurred.
            a.Wait();
        });
```

My concern here is that I think this spins up another thread just to handle the continuation?  The whole reason I used the FromAsync method was to try and avoid doing that.  Also, as you can see in this example, I am a little unsure how exactly to best make sure any exceptions get back to the caller.  I am trying this trick with the wait to force the continuation task to rethrow the exception but it does not feel quite right.

The second approach I am looking at uses a lambda for the 'endMethod' argument:

```
return Task.Factory
    .FromAsync<int>(
        beginMethod: command.BeginExecuteNonQuery,
        endMethod: (asyncResult =>
            {
                int test = command.EndExecuteNonQuery(asyncResult);
                command.Dispose();
                connection.Dispose();
                return test;
            }),
        state: null);
```

On the surface this seems like a nicer approach although I have no idea why it feels that way.  I also feel like this would not spin up a second thread but I am not entirely sure about that.  Also, in this case I have absolutely no idea how to propagate an exception to the caller were one to occur.  Actually, I am not even sure how to identify if an exception has occurred.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: When you say you can't use .Net 4.5, does that mean you can't use C# 5.0? You can use C# 5.0 on .Net 4.0 using `Microsfot.Bcl.Async`, but it requires VS 2012+.

Comment: Well then, I guess I cannot use C# 5.0.  I cannot use the async and await keywords.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `async/await`, it can be quite tedious to make sure `IDisposable` objects get correctly disposed, if they're shared across multiple `Task.ContinueWith` callbacks.

To facilitate this, you can exploit another kind of compiler-generated state machine code: `IEnumerator` methods. This would allow to have pseudo-linear code flow and use `try/finally` and `using` statements as usual. E.g., the following is based on [Stephen Toub's `Iterate` pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx?Redirected=true):

```
static IEnumerator<Task> GetSequenceOfTasks()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(base._ConnectionString))
    {
        yield return TestConnectionAsync(connection);
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SomeProcedure", connection))
        {
            yield return ExecuteCommandAsync(command);
        }
    }
}

// ...

// task will complete when ExecuteCommandAsync has completed
var task = GetSequenceOfTasks().RunAsync();

// ...

// execute a sequence of tasks, propagate exceptions and cancellation (if any)
public static class TaskExt
{
    public static Task<object> RunAsync(this IEnumerator<Task> @this)
    {
        if (@this == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        Action<Task> nextStep = null;
        nextStep = (previousTask) =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (previousTask.IsCanceled)
                    tcs.SetCanceled();
                else if (previousTask.IsFaulted)
                    tcs.SetException(previousTask.Exception);
                else
                {
                    // move to the next task
                    if (@this.MoveNext())
                    {
                        @this.Current.ContinueWith(nextStep,
                            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
                    }
                    else
                        tcs.SetResult(previousTask);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tcs.TrySetException(ex);
            }
        };

        nextStep(Task.FromResult(Type.Missing));

        return tcs.Task.ContinueWith(
            completedTask => { @this.Dispose(); return completedTask; },
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously).Unwrap();
    }
}
```